How to assure persistence of alarms created via Chrome extension API?
The official documentation says this about alarms persistence:

Alarms generally persist until an extension is updated. However, this is not guaranteed, and alarms may be cleared when the browser is restarted. Consequently, consider setting a value in storage when an alarm is created, and then ensure it exists each time your service worker starts up.

What I find missing is a way to assure the worker actually starts up in case the alarms get cleared. Is there a recommended event which the worker should register for (other than the alarm event) in order to assure it gets started to re-create the alarm?

Normally, onInstalled and onStartup (when the browser loads your user profile at startup) events should suffice to check the alarm and recreate it if there was none.
// Not checking `reason` as we want to run this both when the extension
// was installed/updated or the browser was updated.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(initAlarms);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(initAlarms);

function initAlarms() {
  chrome.alarms.get('foo', alarm =>
    if (!alarm) chrome.alarms.create('foo', { periodInMinutes: 60 });
  });
}

The documentation suggests doing it every time the service worker wakes up regardless of the cause i.e. just call initAlarms() instead of using chrome events, which isn't a bad idea in this case since the check is simple.

Does it handle the case of "alarms may be cleared when the browser is restarted" (quote from the doc)? I thought onInstalled fires less often than that (like in your comment - browser being updated, not just restarted).

I was thinking of something like https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#event-onStartup - this one looks like the closest to what I have in mind

The documentation suggests doing it every time the service worker wakes up for whatever reason (for other events or when re-enabling the extension), which isn't a bad idea since the check is simple, but normally onInstalled and onStartup (when the browser is restarted) events should suffice.
